# Some question about a power stabilizer

Tags: stabilizer

I need to use [this](http://www.block.eu/en_IN/products/589824.htm) stabilizer for a sensitive electronics equipment. The equipment is at outdoors so this was recommended by some before me to possible suppress spikes urges ect. Aside from an isolation transformer I have never encountered such device before even the name. It has mains input(I guess the grey plug) and output(I guess the black socket) and a rocker switch on it. And in the data sheet not much is written.

Did anyone have encountered such device? It seems like an isolation transformer with extra filters embedded?

I'm also stuck with another point that whether I need an RCD before this device. I have been told that there is no RCD where the equipment will be placed. Or since this unit has isolation transformer RCD would be redundant?

Comment: I'd heartily recommend to contact the supplier. They usually will be very happy to tell you what's good about their device!

Comment: Some of the wording suggests it being a ferro-resonant transformer, but then other specifications suggest that it is not. Contact the supplier.